# How to get value of const from string in C?

Tags: c

Here we have declared some read-only references in C language:

```
#define KEY_A       4
#define KEY_B       5
#define KEY_C       6
#define KEY_D       7
#define KEY_E       8
#define KEY_F       9
#define KEY_G       10
#define KEY_H       11
#define KEY_I       12
```

We can get value simply by calling the const like `var = KEY_G` but what if we parse a text and use it's content to actually set the `var`? Is there any function like `var = get_const_by_string("KEY_G")` to get content of const by knowing it's name?

Comment: Those aren't "read-only references" - they are preprocessor (macro) definitions. They get replaced by the preprocessor (they do not exist at runtime) - you can read up on them [in the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace)

Comment: C does not even support references. And it has no symbolic constants other than _enum-constants_ either. Such basics are explained in every C book (it need not even be a good one).

Answer (score 3):

Because macro expansion occurs prior to compilation, there is nothing that can do this automatically. You could of course write your own function:

```
int get_const_by_string(char* var){
    if(strcmp(var,"KEY_A") == 0) return KEY_A;
    if(strcmp(var,"KEY_B") == 0) return KEY_B;
    if(strcmp(var,"KEY_C") == 0) return KEY_C;
    if(strcmp(var,"KEY_D") == 0) return KEY_D;
    if(strcmp(var,"KEY_E") == 0) return KEY_E;
    if(strcmp(var,"KEY_F") == 0) return KEY_F;
    if(strcmp(var,"KEY_G") == 0) return KEY_G;
    if(strcmp(var,"KEY_H") == 0) return KEY_H;
    if(strcmp(var,"KEY_I") == 0) return KEY_I;
    return -1;  /*error flag*/
}
```

For an even larger list of constants you could do something like create a hash table for them, but for only 9 or so that might be overkill.